# Prove that intersection with each sub vector space is contained with the intersection of the sum of those vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find a way to prove the following:

Let there be $U, W_1, W_2$ sub vector spaces of linear space V

Prove that: $(U\cap W_1 ) + (U\cap W_2 ) \subseteq U \cap (W_1+W_2 )$

Logically, I can think see it, as the sum of $W_1 +W_2 $ is larger, but I can't think of the steps to take to prove it.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: On the left side, vectors are $v= v_{1} + v_{2}$ with $v_{1} \in U \cap W_{1}$, $v_{2} \in U \cap W_{2}$, which means $v \in U$ (since $U$ is closed under addition). Can you show that this vector is in $U \cap W_{1} + W_{2}$?

Comment: @Eatay Mizrachi If $U, U', W$ are three subspaces of a fixed vector space $V$, then $U, U' \subseteq U+U'$ by definition of the sum, $W \cap U, W \cap U' \subseteq W \cap (U+U')$ by elementary set theory and finally $(W \cap U)+(W \cap U') \subseteq W \cap (U+U')$ again by definition of the notion of sum of subspaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $(U \cap W_1) + (U \cap W_2) \subseteq W \cap (W_1 + W_2)$, we will take an arbitrary element of $(U \cap W_1) + (U \cap W_2)$ and show that it is in the set $U \cap(W_1+W_2)$.

Let $x \in (U \cap W_1) + (U \cap W_2)$. By definition, there exist vectors $ x_1 \in (U \cap W_1)$ and $x_2 \in (U \cap W_2)$ such that $x=x_1+x_2$. Observe the following:

- Because $x_1 \in U \cap W_1$, then $x_1 \in U$ and $x_1 \in W_1$.
- Because $x_2 \in U \cap W_2$, then $x_2 \in U$ and $x_2 \in W_2$.

$U$, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are vector spaces and thus are closed under vector addition. So,

- $x_1 \in U$, $x_2 \in U$, therefore $x=x_1+x_2 \in U$
- $x_1 \in W_1$, $\textbf{0}_\textbf{V} \in W_2$, therefore $x_1=x_1+\textbf{0}_\textbf{V} \in (W_1+W_2)$
- $x_2 \in W_2$, $\textbf{0}_\textbf{V} \in W_1$, therefore $x_2=x_2+\textbf{0}_\textbf{V}\in (W_1 + W_2)$
- $x_1 \in (W_1 + W_2)$, $x_2 \in (W_1 + W_2)$, therefore $x = x_1 + x_2 \in (W_1 + W_2)$
- $x \in (W_1 + W_2)$, $x \in U$, therefore $x \in U \cap (W_1+W_2)$

This concludes the proof.

Comment: My man! Thank you for the detailed answer. :)

Comment: You're welcome, best of luck.